# Profit of drawing a ball game

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

An urn 1 contains 2 red and 8 white balls.

An urn 2 contains 4 red and 6 white balls.

A ball is drawn from each urn.

(a) Give a suitable probability space.

(b) Tim receives 1 Euro if the ball from urn 1 is red. Lena receives 1 euro if the
Ball from urn 2 is white.

Give the mapping rule for a random variable X that describes the profit of Tim, and a random variable Y, which describes Lena's profit.

Find the joint distribution of X and Y. Are X and Y independent?

(c) Mia receives 1 Euro for each red ball that is drawn.

Give the mapping rule for a random variable Z that describes the profit of Mia. Find the joint distribution of X from exercise (b) and Z. Are X and Z independent?

$$$$

(a) Is the outcome space $\Omega = \{\text{red}, \text{white}, \text{red}, \text{white}\}$ and so $p(\text{red})=p(\text{white})=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

(b) Do we have that $X,Y\in \{0,1\}$. What is meant by mapping rule? Do we have to write a formula?

Comment: I would have said the possible outcomes were $(R,R), (R,W), (W,R),(W,W)$ and you need to compute the probability of each.  And it is not clear what you mean by, say, p(red).  What outcome are you referring to?

Comment: Ah ok! So we have the outcome space $\Omega =\{ (R,R), (R,W), (W,R),(W,W)\}$ and the probability of each of these outcomes is the same and equal to $\frac{1]{4}$, right? @lulu

Comment: Nope.  Take the first one, $(R,R)$.  That means you get a red ball from each urn. What's the probability that you draw red from the first urn?  the second?  Note that the draws are independent.  That is, knowing which color you got from the first urn tells you nothing about the other draw.

Comment: Just intuitively:  There are a lot more white balls than red balls, in both urns.  So $(W,W)$ should be considerably more probable than $(R,R)$, say.

Comment: Do we have that $$ p((R,R))=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{8} \\ p((R,W))=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{12} \\ p((W,R))=\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{32} \\ p((W,W))=\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{48}$$ ? @lulu

Comment: Well...do those sum to $1$?

Comment: You should always think about the numbers you compute.  For instance, in an earlier comment I pointed out that there are many more whites than reds in both urns, so $P(W,W)>P(R,R)$.  And yet you get something very different.  That should have been a sign that your answers were very wrong.

Comment: Ah no... my previous comment is wrong....  It should be : $$p((R,R))=\frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac{4}{10}=\frac{2}{25} \\ p((R,W))=\frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac{6}{10}=\frac{3}{25} \\ p((W,R))=\frac{8}{10}\cdot \frac{4}{10}=\frac{8}{25} \\ p((W,W))=\frac{8}{10}\cdot \frac{6}{10}=\frac{12}{25}$$ right? @lulu

Comment: That looks good!

Comment: Great!! Could you give me a hint for (b) ? Do we have to write all possible values for $$ and $Y$ ? Or what are we supposed to do? @lulu

Comment: All that is needed for the rest is to write out the payoff structure.  For instance $X(R,R)=1$ and so on.  That lets you compute $P(X)=1$$ quickly.

Comment: So we have $$X(R,R)=1 \\ X(R,W)= 1\\ X(W,R)=0 \\ X(W,W)=0$$ right? What do you mean by $P(X)=1$ ? Respectively, for $Y$ we have : $$X(R,R)=0 \\ X(R,W)= 1\\ X(W,R)=0 \\ X(W,W)=1$$ right? @lulu

Comment: You are right about the first part...so then $P(X)=1$ would be $P(R,R)+P(R,W)$ and you have already computed those.

Comment: I haven't really understood what $P$ is. Could you explain that further to me? Is it the name of the map? @lulu

Comment: Writing $P(X=1)$ is shorthand for "the probability that $X=1$".  I see that I put the parentheses in the wrong place in my earlier comment.  Since $X=1$ only in the cases $(R,R)$ and $(R,W)$ we see that $P(X=1)=P(R,R)+P(R,W)=\frac 2{25}+\frac 3{25}=\frac 15$.

Comment: Ahh ok! So we have $$P(X=1)=P(R,R)+P(R,W)=\frac 2{25}+\frac 3{25}=\frac 15 \\ P(X=0)=P(W,R)+P(W,W)=\frac{8}{25}+\frac{12}{25}=\frac{4}{5} $$ and respectively $$P(Y=1)=P(R,W)+P(W,W)=\frac{3}{25}+\frac{12}{25}=\frac{3}{5} \\ P(Y=0)=P(R,R)+P(W,R)=\frac{2}{25}+\frac{8}{25}=\frac{2}{5} $$ Is that correct? So the mapping rules are these $P$'s ? @lulu

Comment: I have never heard the phrase "mapping rule" but I would have to think that it is this, more or less.

Comment: As I understand it is as we say at functions $f:A \rightarrow B, x\mapsto f(x)$. So in this case $f$ is $X$ or $P$ ? @lulu

Comment: Do we have $X:(\Omega, P)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $X((R,R))=1 , X((R,W))= 1, X((W,R))=0 , X((W,W))=0$ and $P(X=1)=\frac 15 , P(X=0)=\frac{4}{5}$ ? @lulu

Comment: I would check with whatever reference (or person) set this problem.  It could refer to the map from $\Omega\to \{0,1\}$, namely $X(R,R)=\frac 25$ and so on.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-) @lulu